# Multiplication Table issue

Tags: c, malloc, multiplication, calloc

I am trying to write a C function to store a multiplication table from the range 0-x. The function I have written has a bug in it where it only stores either the first 2 or 3 rows of the table and the function is also never returning a value and I am very confused, any help is appreciated.

```
void makeTable (int x) {
int** table = malloc(x * sizeof(int*));
int i;
int q;
int* ptr;
for(i = 0; i <= x; i++){
    ptr = calloc(x, sizeof(int));
    for(q = 0; q <= x; q++){
        ptr[q] = (i * q);
    }
    table[i] = ptr;
}
return table;
```

}

Comment: If you have an array of size `x`, the last accessible element is indexed by `x-1`

Comment: Your function is declared `void`, when it wants to return an `int **`. Compiler warnings should have caught this.

Answer (score 1):

Here you access memory that you have not allocated. That is undefined behavior.

Correct would be to consider `x` elements not `x+1`.

```
for(q = 0; q < x; q++){
        ptr[q] = (i * q);
```

Same goes with the outer loop also.

```
for(i = 0; i < x; i++){
```

Also few other things - returning from a function which is declared void (Undefined behavior). Not checking the return value of `malloc` and `calloc` is problematic.

So correct way to write the function would be

```
int** makeTable (int x) {
    int** table = malloc(x * sizeof *table);
    if(!table)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in mem alloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < x; i++){
        int * ptr = calloc(x, sizeof *ptr);
        if(!ptr)
        {
           fprintf(stderr,"Error in mem alloc");
           exit(1);
        }
        for(size_t q = 0; q < x; q++){
            ptr[q] = (i * q);
        }
        table[i] = ptr;
    }
    return table;
}
```

Also somewhere in this program you should add the logic to free all these dynamically allocated memory using `free`.